# Finding the arc length of the parabola $y=x^2 \; from \; (0,0)\;to\;(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

As the title says, I need to find the arc length of that. This is what I have so far (I'm mostly stuck on the integration part): $${dy\over dx}=2x \Rightarrow L=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(2x)^2}dx$$
Substitute $$x=\tan\theta, \qquad dx=\sec^2\theta\,d\theta ,$$
giving $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(2\tan\theta)^2}\sec^2\theta\,d\theta=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+4\tan^2\theta}\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$$
That is where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150745/28900).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $2x = \tan\theta$ instead. Then, the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_0^{\arctan 2} \sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta} \cdot \dfrac14\sec^2\theta \ \mathrm d\theta$ which is equal to $\displaystyle \frac14 \int_0^{\arctan2} \sec^3\theta \ \mathrm d\theta$.

Comment: Oh duh, I completely forgot about 2x. Let me try it now and see what I get. I think I remember a problem similar to this where I kept getting stuck.

Comment: After this substitution (and pulling the constant factor out) the integrand is $\sec^3 \theta$, not $\sec^4 \theta$---this significantly changes the mechanics of evaluating the integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: @KennyLau You might find this weird, but I'm in calc 2 in college and have never learned about changing the bounds, so I'm completely lost as to why and how to do that. But if I continue by using the fact that $2x = tan(\theta)$ I still get stuck. This is where I'm at, $${1\over2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+{{tan^2(\theta)}\over4}}*sec^2(\theta)d\theta$$

Comment: @Travis Is it valid to do this, ${tan(\theta)\over2}x =tan(\theta)$? That seems really messed up, and I don't think it helps.

Comment: @Travis sorry, corrected.

Comment: @DevHeavy No, that is not a legal maneuver. If you set $2x = \tan \theta$, then you get the integrand Kenny gives in his answer.

Comment: @DevHeavy: Try to keep in mind that if you change the variable, you need to change the limits.  And the way you change the limits is the same way you change the variable.  In this case, the relation is $2x = \tan\theta$, so $\theta = \arctan(2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You give:

$L=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(2x)^2}dx$

Rearranging:

$L=2\int_0^1 \sqrt{{1\over4}+x^2}dx$

From an [integral table](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf) (29):

$\int \sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx ={1\over2}x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+{1\over2}a^2\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})+C$

...where $a$ in this case is ${1\over2}$.

So

$L =x\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}}+{1\over4}\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}})+C$

Since we're measuring from the vertex we want $L=0$ at $x=0$, so:

${1\over4}\ln\sqrt{{1\over4}}+C=0$

$C={1\over4}\ln2$

$L =x\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}}+{1\over4}\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}})+{1\over4}\ln2$

$L =x\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}}+{1\over4}\ln(2x+\sqrt{4x^2+1})$

At $x=1$:

$L =\sqrt{{5\over4}}+{1\over4}\ln(2+\sqrt{5})$

$L ={1\over2}\sqrt{5}+{1\over4}\ln(2+\sqrt{5})$

$L\approx1.4789428575445...$

Answer (score -1):

You can make the substitution $2x=sh(t)$ it is simple ot obtain the result.